# How to make validation with the following conditions?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, passwords

Username : at least 5 letters and all lowercase letters
Password : is a combination of 2-digit numbers followed by the symbol "@" or the symbol "&" and followed by 4 uppercase letters

Example :
Username : meatball / jungernaut
Password : 21@YOUR / 74&GOOD

IAM TRY

```
var slt = "gordonbam"
var sltk = "12@BANA"
var username =  /[1-5][A-Z]/g;
var password = /[1-2](@|&)\w[1-4][A-Z]/g;

var result1 = slt.match(username);
var result2 = sltk.match(password);

console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
```

Comment: Did you attempt anything?

Comment: Provide any solutions you have tried. More likely to get help from the community when doing so.

Comment: why I find it very difficult to understand regular expressions ?

Comment: PLEASE see [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48345922/3600709). DO NOT VALIDATE PASSWORDS ON CLIENT SIDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe,

```
^[0-9]{2}[@&][A-Z]{4}$
```

and

```
^[a-z]{5,}$
```

might work OK for pass and username.

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/JmPc5P/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/JmPc5P/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

```js
const regex = /^\d{2}[@&][A-Z]{4}$/gm;
const str = `21@YOUR
74&GOOD
74&aaaa
74&AAAz`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: function password(pw) {
    fpassword = /[0-9]{3}[*][a-z]{3}$/;
 console.log(fpassword.test(pw));
 
}
password("111*sss");
password("123*try");

Answer (score 0):

for Username:

```
^([a-z]*[a-z]){5}[a-z]*$
```

for Password:

```
^[0-9]{2}[@][A-Z]{4}$
```

try this and if there is any problem then comment me